# Azure APIM invoking a service in AKS cluster

Tags: azure-aks

Inside an Azure VNET, I have an AKS cluster with some services. I also have an APIM within the same VNET and is currently configured to invoke API's on the service via its IP address. Is there a way to invoke the service not via its IP address? In other words I would like to configure the service endpoint on APIM without referring to its IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can configure the service endpoint on APIM without referring to its IP address by using DNS names. You can create a DNS record for the service in Azure DNS or any other DNS provider and then use that DNS name as the endpoint for the service in APIM. This way, you can avoid using the IP address of the service and instead use a more human-readable name.

To use a DNS name for the service endpoint in APIM, you need to update the backend URL of the APIM API to use the DNS name instead of the IP address. You can do this by editing the APIM API in the Azure portal or by using the Azure API Management REST API.

First you need to expose your AKS service using an Ingress Controller which will provide you with a DNS hostname. Install an Ingress Controller in your AKS cluster.

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/main/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

Create an Ingress Resource to expose your service.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: addon-http-application-routing
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myservice.20e1af6debef4433b8ab.eastus.aksapp.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

If you have a custom domain name then

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myservice.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Replace `myservice.example.com` with your desired DNS name and `my-service` with your actual service name and apply using `kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml`

[image]

If you are using custom domain then create a DNS record in Azure DNS or another DNS provider to point to the external IP of your Ingress Controller.

```
kubectl get services -o wide -w --namespace ingress-nginx
```

Create a DNS A Record in Azure DNS or with your DNS provider that points myservice.example.com to the external IP obtained from the previous step.

If you don't have a custom domain and you want to demonstrate the functionality within Azure using a free domain, you can use the Azure provided domain for your services. When you set up an HTTP application routing solution in AKS, it automatically assigns a DNS name to your service., look for the `HOSTS` column, which will have an auto-generated DNS name ending with the zone name retrieved earlier.
[image]

Now you can use this auto-generated DNS name as the backend service URL in Azure API Management.
Update the APIM backend service to use the DNS name.

1. **Navigate to the Azure Portal** and go to your APIM instance.
2. **Select APIs** from the side menu.
3. **Choose the API** you want to configure.
4. **Select the Backend** tab.
5. **Add or Update the Backend** with the DNS name of your service (`myservice.example.com`) or the auto generated DNS name
   [image]

After updating the backend service in APIM, Call the API from APIM and ensure that it is routing the requests to your AKS service using the DNS name.
By following these steps, you should be able to configure the service endpoint in APIM to use a DNS name instead of an IP address.

References:

- [Use Azure API Management with microservices deployed in Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-kubernetes#deploy-api-management-in-front-of-aks)
- [Create a private Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/private-clusters#options-for-connecting-to-the-private-cluster)